# Best way to alter/update millions of SQL Server records using .NET (not T-SQL)?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL Server table with around 8 million records for a research project, and I need to calculate a few values for each record and save these in the record. The calculation is rather complex, so my lack of T-SQL knowledge means that I want to do the processing using .net although T-SQL scripting is no doubt the best choice.

My approach is simple, but still it fails. I am using a data reader (with its own connection) to iterate over all the records. I am using another connection to create command the execute the updates using a stored procedure. After around a million it fails with a timeout error.

I tried with the EF at first, but that was slow and I had difficulties preventing out of memory exceptions even though I tried a range of various approaches.

What is the best way to do this using .net? Am i using the connections wrong? I've read that a bad use of multiple connections can result in timeout exceptions.

Heres an example of the code (VB.NET):

```vb
Public Sub UpdateRecords()

    Dim ReadConnection As New SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
    Dim WriteConnection As New SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
    Dim Reader As SqlDataReader
    Dim ReadCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim WriteCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim Transaction As SqlTransaction

    ReadConnection.Open()
    ReadCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from records", ReadConnection)
    Reader = ReadCommand.ExecuteReader
    If Reader.HasRows Then
        WriteConnection.Open()
        Transaction = WriteConnection.BeginTransaction
        Do While Reader.Read
            WriteCommand = New SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", WriteConnection, Transaction)
            'calculate
            'set parameters
            WriteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Loop
        Transaction.Commit()
        WriteConnection.Close()
    End If
    Reader.Close()
    ReadConnection.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: *What is the best way to do this using .net?* Learn Transact-SQL. Use a `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to execute a Transact-SQL query that updates your data.

Comment: The **best way** to do this would be to use **T-SQL** .... and update all those rows *directly on the server* !

Comment: I know this (as I also state in the question), but if speed of processing (it will run once during a night) and best practice is no concern (its a research project), but the speed of me learning T-SQL is a concern, then how can it be done using .net?

Comment: could you share with us the calculations? Maybe someone can help you out translating the calculation into T-SQL, because doing this from .net could bring up some pretty ugly timeout and performance issues. Dealing with 8 million records one by one is going to kill the server/computer you run the program on. It's not only you have to calculate results for each record, you have to first stream those records to your computer...

Comment: Your case is one that practically begs for an SQL solution, as C#/VB are **spectacularly unsuited** for this type of task. How about asking us how you can write the `update` statement you need instead?

Comment: @RaduPorumb (and Gonzix) I might end up doing that, I can definitely see the point of learning T-SQL in the long run, and if I choose to got that way, part of the learning will be through SO.

Comment: @SuppaiKamo You don't really need to learn T-SQL top to bottom to write an update statement. I asked you to show us what type of calculations you want to do because I suspect it's trivial to write. What isn't trivial is wrapping it in some sort of batch that only takes a chunk of all your records at a time, because even a trivial update on 8 million rows can be made faster by breaking it up into smaller pieces.

Comment: Try it without using a Transaction. A Transaction that only wraps a single record update is not all that useful anyway. I'd also throw some intentional delay in there somewhere. Application.doEvents on the client side might help if the PC is trashing and causing the timeout. And/or just call a delay for a few seconds every 100 records or so to allow the server to catch up. You may just be sending more transactions per second than your server can handle gracefully. You are running a very tight loop here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there are so many records, it is not feasible to load all of them and then update them one by one. Especially if you have to make the calculations in VB.NET.

I suggest that you load them in batches, calculate each batch and finally update them back in batches as well (the batch size should be set to a value that doesn't make the calculations last forever per batch).

As to how you can update in batches, I'm [going to leave this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25241966/c-sharp-and-sqlserver-normalizing-large-sets-of-urls/25242198#25242198). It's tells about how you can use structured parameters to update/insert.

Other alternatives include:

1. Implement the calculations in a [CLR assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.110).aspx). This will allow you to call it directly from TSQL. So you will be able to move the entire process to the database server.
2. Implement the calculations directly in TSQL as others have pointed out, but that depends on how complex they are. They could become hard to maintain.

Comment: Ok, i was hoping for something simpler, but I get the point. I will however use the very rough approach of simply using offset/fetch t-sql to retrieve records in batches, and for each of those store data locally and close connection, and subsequently update the batch. It should work. it'll be slow as hell, but it will be fast enough :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @SuppaiKamo: No problem. That would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `SqlBulkCopy` class provided in .NET. This class is meant to do what you need.

The following code will help you. Though I wrote it on the fly and is not tested, it will give you and idea how to proceed in this matter.

```
Sub DoBulkCopy(ByVal sourceConnectionString As String, ByVal sourceTableSelectStatement As String, ByVal destinationConnectionString As String, ByVal destinationTableName As String)
    Try
        Using sourceConnection As New SqlConnection(SourceConnectionString)
            Using sourceCommand As New SqlCommand(sourceTableSelectStatement)
                sourceCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
                sourceCommand.Connection = sourceConnection
                sourceConnection.Open()
                Using sourceReader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = sourceCommand.ExecuteReader
                    If sourceReader.HasRows Then
                        Using destinationConnection As New SqlConnection(destinationConnectionString)
                            destinationConnection.Open()
                            Using transaction As SqlTransaction = destinationConnection.BeginTransaction
                                Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction)
                                    '' If the data source and the destination table have the same number of columns, and the ordinal position of each source column 
                                    '' within the data source matches the ordinal position of the corresponding destination column, the ColumnMappings collection is unnecessary. 
                                    '' However, if the column counts differ, or the ordinal positions are not consistent, you must use ColumnMappings to 
                                    '' make sure that data is copied into the correct columns.
                                    '' ** Uncomment and modify the following commented lines if necessary. **
                                    'With bulkCopy.ColumnMappings
                                    '    .Add("Column1", "Column1")
                                    'End With

                                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName
                                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceReader)
                                    transaction.Commit()
                                End Using
                            End Using
                            destinationConnection.Close()
                        End Using
                    End If
                End Using
                sourceConnection.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As to your problem of it working for a while and then timing out, my guess is that this is the problem:

```
Transaction = WriteConnection.BeginTransaction
    Do While Reader.Read
        WriteCommand = New SqlCommand("StoredProcedure", WriteConnection, Transaction)
        'calculate
        'set parameters
        WriteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Loop
```

In other words, you're updating your 8 million records one by one in a single transaction. You're very likely blowing out the transaction log in your database. If you're the only one using this database (you state that it's a research project), I'd backup the database and either move the `transaction.commit()` inside your loop or get rid of the transaction altogether (since SQL Server uses implicit transactions, these should be the same thing). If something goes wrong, your rollback is a database restore.

Once you're done putting out this fire, I'd set about learning T-SQL; you can only go so far using the wrong tool for the job.